# Mongodb db.loadServerScripts(); fatal error missing } after property list nofile_b:2

Tags: mongodb

Estou tentando executar o comando `db.loadServerScripts();` mas está retornando o seguinte erro:

```
SyntaxError: missing } after property list nofile_b:2
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Bem vindo ao SoPT. Favor postar suas perguntas em português. Abraço

Comment: Quais documentos existem na sua collection system.js   ?

Comment: 3 mil registros